# Error in preg_replace () → preg_replace_callback () rewriting? [Smarty_Compiler.class.php]

Tags: php, zend-framework, smarty

After upgrading PHP to version 7, Warning appeared in Smarty_Compiler.class.php.

> Warning: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is no longer supported, use preg_replace_callback instead in /var/www/……/Smarty/Smarty_Compiler.class.php on line 271

Looking at the error location ...... ↓

```
$source_content = preg_replace($search.'e', "'"
                                   . $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter) . 'php'
                                   . "' . str_repeat(\"\n\", substr_count('\\0', \"\n\")) .'"
                                   . $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter)
                                   . "'"
                                   , $source_content);
```

Preg_replace () seemed to be unusable, and I changed it to preg_replace_callback ().

```
$source_content = preg_replace_callback($search
                                   , function($matches) {
                                         return  "'" 
                                                . $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter) . 'php'
                                                . "' . str_repeat(\"\n\", substr_count('" . $matches[0] . "', \"\n\")) .'"
                                                . $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter)
                                                . "'";
                                     }
                                   , $source_content);
```

Then, Smarty error appeared this time ... ....

> Fatal error: Smarty error: [in PATH]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: php' . str_repeat(" ", substr_count('{*version {$ZEND_VERSION (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 458) in /var/www/……/Smarty/Smarty.class.php on line 1095

In the place where the error occurred, the version information is commented out.
Before upgrading PHP it worked properly, so I think that I made mistakes in preg_replace_callback () rewriting, but I do not know where wrong ...
Also, I'm not sure what this process of Smarty_Compiler.class.php is doing...
If you are familiar with PHP or Smarty, please let me know.

Comment: Don't quote `str_repeat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Smarty](https://www.smarty.net/) is a template engine, a library, and you shouldn't be modifying its code yourself. Instead try to upgrade the version you use to the newest one. It seems that it's supporting PHP7.

Comment: When examining the version, it was Smarty 2.6,
I will upgrade to 3 series.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
    $source_content = preg_replace_callback($search,
        function($matches) {
            return
                $this->_quote_replace($this->left_delimiter) . 'php' . str_repeat(
                    $this->_quote_replace("\n"),
                    substr_count($matches[0], $this->_quote_replace("\n"))
                )
                . $this->_quote_replace($this->right_delimiter);
          },
          $source_content
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still use smarty 2.6, try to update smarty_compiler.class.php to this
[Smarty_Compiler.class.php on Github](https://github.com/smarty-php/smarty/blob/support/2.6/libs/Smarty_Compiler.class.php)

It works above 7.1 PHP version on latest PHP 7.4., maybe 8. I did not test it.

Upgrade to higher version is maybe next step, but I dont know yet, if all smarty templates is compatible. So if you have plenty of templates, this is fastest solution to fix it.